# Read Excel Data (Rich Excel Data)

Tags: php, excel

I want to read data form an **Excel** file and show in **html**. I know there are several libraries like [**PHPExcel**](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/), [**PHP-ExelReader**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/) that do so.

But, I also want to keep the format that was in excel file.
For example :

**−19×10<sup>−17</sup> J** should be parsed as `−19&times;10<sup>−17</sup> J` And
**m<sub>1</sub>r<sub>1</sub> : m<sub>2</sub>r<sub>2</sub>** as `m<sub>1</sub>r<sub>1</sub> : m<sub>2</sub>r<sub>2</sub>`.

Is there any library that could do so? I have googled but did not get any solution for this. Please recommend some libraries or any tutorial for this task.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

**Update**  - I also want to store data in database.

Comment: PHPExcel has an HTML Writer that can be used to generate markup from rich-text data in the Excel cells

Comment: @MarkBaker.. Do they have any documentation about that?

Comment: @MarkBaker.. I also want to store data in database.

Comment: What level of documentation do you need? There's Developer docs available in the distribution, together with API docs, loads of examples in the /Tests directory, and it's all open source so you can look at the code as well.

Comment: It won't write to a database for you, but you can read cell data and create your own insert statements from that

Comment: Ok.. Thanks @MarkBaker for the great support. I'll check it out. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the solution. It's **[PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)**.

While fetching values from cells, what i did is as following.

```
$value = $cell->getValue();
if($value instanceof PHPExcel_RichText)
{
    $cellValueAsString = '';
    $elements = $value->getRichTextElements();
    foreach ($elements as $element)
    {
        if ($element instanceof PHPExcel_RichText_Run) 
        {
            if ($element->getFont()->getSuperScript()) 
            {
                $cellValueAsString .= '<sup>';
            } 
            else if ($element->getFont()->getSubScript()) 
            {
                $cellValueAsString .= '<sub>';
            }
        }

        $cellText = $element->getText();
        $cellValueAsString .= htmlspecialchars($cellText);
        if ($element instanceof PHPExcel_RichText_Run) 
        {
            if ($element->getFont()->getSuperScript()) 
            {
                $cellValueAsString .= '</sup>';
            } 
            else if ($element->getFont()->getSubScript()) 
            {
                $cellValueAsString .= '</sub>';
            }
        }
    }

    $value = $cellValueAsString;
}
```